# Issues ordering variables, bar labels, and legend labels from smallest to largest in a horizontal stacked bar graph in R using GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to order this bar graph from smallest (0) to largest (5), however, I'm not able to get the graph to visualize how I'd like it to. I'm either having an issue where the wrong values are displayed for each category, or where the legend is displayed in reverse order.

Background:
I'm creating a stacked bargraph of population in three different years displayed horizontally, with the population number data in each year grouped by age group. Agegroup and year are coded as categorical variables. I'm also using the sjlabelled package to more easily get and set labels.

Option 1:
My code:

```
bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-factor(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, levels=c("35+" = 5, "30-34" = 4, "25-29" = 3, "20 to 24" = 2, "18-19" = 1, "<18" = 0))
    bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-set_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, labels=c("<18" = 0, "18-19" = 1, "20 to 24" = 2, "25-29" = 3, "30-34" = 4, "35+" = 5))
    ggplot(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years, aes(fill=agegroup_redef, y=N, x=year, label=label_numberformat(N)))+
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
      scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=7, minor_breaks=seq(0, 700000, 50000), labels=label_numberformat)+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$year))+
      scale_fill_manual(values=palette_households, labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef))+
      labs(x="", y="", fill="Age Group", title="Boston's Population by Age Group, 1980-2023")+
      theme(legend.position="bottom", 
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=1),
            panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=2),
            text=element_text(family="Open Sans"),
            title=element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=20),
            legend.title = element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=14),
            legend.text = element_text(size=12),
            legend.box.margin=margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(0,  "lines"),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, -40, 0, 0)),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, 0, 0,0), family="Open Sans Semibold", color="black"))+
      geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),
                color="black",
                size=3.85,
                family="Open Sans Semibold",
      )+ coord_flip()
```

The display:
[correct values corresponding to correct age group categories, legend is displaying from smallest to largest agegroup category number, but showing up on graph as largest agegroup on the left to smallest agegroup on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQOWq.png)

The issue: While the correct numbers are being displayed for each agegroup category and the legend is displaying the agegroups in ascending order, the bars are stacked from largest to smallest, and I'd like them to be reversed.

Option 2:
My code:

```
 bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-factor(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, levels=c("<18" = 0, "18-19" = 1, "20 to 24" = 2, "25-29" = 3, "30-34" = 4, "35+" = 5))
    bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-set_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, labels=c("<18" = 0, "18-19" = 1, "20 to 24" = 2, "25-29" = 3, "30-34" = 4, "35+" = 5))
    ggplot(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years, aes(fill=agegroup_redef, y=N, x=year, label=label_numberformat(N)))+
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
      scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=7, minor_breaks=seq(0, 700000, 50000), labels=label_numberformat)+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$year))+
      scale_fill_manual(values=palette_households, labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef))+
      labs(x="", y="", fill="Age Group", title="Boston's Population by Age Group, 1980-2023")+
      theme(legend.position="bottom", 
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=1),
            panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=2),
            text=element_text(family="Open Sans"),
            title=element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=20),
            legend.title = element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=14),
            legend.text = element_text(size=12),
            legend.box.margin=margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(0,  "lines"),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, -40, 0, 0)),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, 0, 0,0), family="Open Sans Semibold", color="black"))+
      geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),
                color="black",
                size=3.85,
                family="Open Sans Semibold",
      )+ coord_flip()
```

The display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQPVQ.png)

The issue: While the bars are stacked in the correct order (from smallest to largest age group), and the legend is in the correct order (from smallest to largest age group), the legend markers themselves are incorrect (i.e. 310170 corresponds to 35+ and so on).

Option 3:
My code:

```
bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-factor(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, levels=c("<18" = 0, "18-19" = 1, "20 to 24" = 2, "25-29" = 3, "30-34" = 4, "35+" = 5))
    bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef<-set_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef, labels=c("<18" = 0, "18-19" = 1, "20 to 24" = 2, "25-29" = 3, "30-34" = 4, "35+" = 5))
    ggplot(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years, aes(fill=rev(agegroup_redef), y=N, x=year, label=label_numberformat(N)))+
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
      scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=7, minor_breaks=seq(0, 700000, 50000), labels=label_numberformat)+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$year))+
      scale_fill_manual(values=palette_households, labels=get_labels(bospop_by_agegroup_all_years$agegroup_redef))+
      labs(x="", y="", fill="Age Group", title="Boston's Population by Age Group, 1980-2023")+
      theme(legend.position="bottom", 
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=1),
            panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(color="gray72", linewidth=0.5, linetype=2),
            text=element_text(family="Open Sans"),
            title=element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=20),
            legend.title = element_text(family="Open Sans Semibold", size=14),
            legend.text = element_text(size=12),
            legend.box.margin=margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(0,  "lines"),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, -40, 0, 0)),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, margin=margin(0, 0, 0,0), family="Open Sans Semibold", color="black"))+
      geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),
                color="black",
                size=3.85,
                family="Open Sans Semibold",
      )+ coord_flip()
```

The display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hepo.png)

The issue: While the legend is in correct order and the categories in the legend correspond correctly to the categories displayed, the order of the stacked bars is from largest to smallest.

I've found that the only way I can get the lowest category (0) to feature on the far left is either by reordering the factor levels from largest to smallest, or using rev(), however, as a consequence, the legend order is from largest to smallest as well. I've tried using rev() in the labels as well however this messes up the order and makes it so that the labels aren't accurate.

I suspect the issue relates to how factors are ordered and the fact that I call coord_flip() but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue... I apologize in advance if this is an easy fix I'm still new to R!
Thank you so much for your help! Please let me know if I can clarify anything further. I appreciate it!

Comment: `geom_bar(position=position_stack(reverse=TRUE), stat="identity")+`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Also, try to make the code as small as possible. All the theme info and fancy axes don't seem directly relevant to the code problem you have and are just adding noise.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon Spring! I added position_stack(reverse=TRUE) to geom_bar and geom_text and it worked!